# Always show first tick label when IsLabelCullingEnabled is true

Tags: wpf, axis-labels, scichart

I posted this on the SciChart forum about a week ago but haven't received an answer yet, so posting here to see if a larger community might have some thoughts.

Using SciChart for WPF, I have a custom LabelProvider and TickProvider implemented for my X axis. In general the label culling works fine, but sometimes it shows the first tick label and starts culling with the second, and other times it starts with the first tick label immediately. I would like to always show the first tick label, and then cull from that point. Is this possible?

[image: This image shows how the label culling should occur]

[image: This image shows how the culling sometimes hides the first label]

I found this post from 5 years ago, which indicates I would need to do the culling myself, but was hoping maybe there would be a better way?

https://www.scichart.com/questions/wpf/always-show-visiberange-minmax-labels-on-x-axis